# Wordpress get src of full image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I try to get full size image src. url by the function:

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'full' );
```

I have notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: full in F:\wamp\www\igniter\wp-includes\media.php on line 71
```

Information (url and sizes) about the file is returned but with this notice.

The problem is in function image_constrain_size_for_editor when I add custom image sizes like this:

```
'custom' => array(
// add image for all post type
   array(
        'width'  => 263, // (1/4 grid)
        'height' => 133,
        'crop'   => true,
    ),
    'masonry' => array(
        'width'  => 360,
        'height' => 1000,
        'crop'   => false,
    ),
```

In file media.php line 70 is:

```
} elseif ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) && count( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) && in_array( $size, array_keys( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) ) ) {
```

in_array function should have strict param to true.
Right now I changed my custom image array to:

```
'custom' => array(
        // add image for all post type
        'grid-1/4' => array(
            'width'  => 263, // (1/4 grid)
            'height' => 133,
            'crop'   => true,
        ),
        'masonry' => array(
            'width'  => 360,
            'height' => 1000,
            'crop'   => false,
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
```

instead of

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'full' );
```

[Refrence](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image#Examples)

Comment: No this is not working. The problem is when I add array with custom image size like this:
'custom' => array(
        // add image for all post type
        array(
            'width'  => 263, // (1/4 grid)
            'height' => 133,
            'crop'   => true,
        ),
        'masonry' => array(
            'width'  => 360,
            .....
        ),
    )
bug is in function image_constrain_size_for_editor line 70:
in_array( $size, array_keys( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) )
should by:
in_array( $size, array_keys( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ), true )